# How to filter objects by price range in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Item` with field `price`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank='true')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My query may contain `min_price` & `max_price` values. So, my request may be like this: `http://example.com/api/items?min_price=50&max_price=500`. Can anybody tell me, how can I query items between min & max values? Can I solve it using Django ORM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check api reference for [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range). Like it states

> You can use range anywhere you can use BETWEEN in SQL — for dates,
>   numbers and even characters.

So, in your case:

```
Item.objects.filter(price__range=(min_price, max_price))
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a FilterSet
For more advanced filtering requirements you can specify a FilterSet class that should be used by the view. For example:

```
import django_filters
from myapp.models import Item
from myapp.serializers import ItemSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class ItemListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='gte')
max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='lte')
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ['min_price', 'max_price']


class ItemList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Item.objects.all()
serializer_class = GameSerializer
filter_class = ItemListFilter
```

Which will allow you to make requests such as:

```
http://example.com/api/games?min_price=1.20&max_price=8.00
```