# Checking for a Range of Values

Tags: django

I could check for a range of values, use the BETWEEN operator.

```
MySQL [distributor]> select prod_name, prod_price from products where prod_price between 3.49 and 11.99;
+---------------------+------------+
| prod_name           | prod_price |
+---------------------+------------+
| Fish bean bag toy   |       3.49 |
| Bird bean bag toy   |       3.49 |
| Rabbit bean bag toy |       3.49 |
| 8 inch teddy bear   |       5.99 |
| 12 inch teddy bear  |       8.99 |
| 18 inch teddy bear  |      11.99 |
| Raggedy Ann         |       4.99 |
| King doll           |       9.49 |
| Queen doll          |       9.49 |
+---------------------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.005 sec)
```

I reference to django docs and found `gte`, `gt`, `lt`, `lte` but no `between`.

How could I achieve the between functionality?

Comment: products.objects.filter(prod_price__range=[3.49 , 11.99])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter objects by price range in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423211/how-to-filter-objects-by-price-range-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in django ORM `products.objects.filter(prod_price__range=(3.49 , 11.99))` ref [for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#range)